# Событие onclick в js

Tags: javascript

Хочу изучить в чистом виде JS, столкнулся с проблемой, не работает:

```
(function () {
    document.getElementById('login').onclick = function () {
        alert(123);
        return false;
    };
})();

<a href="#" id="login">Войти</a>
```

Можно обойтись просто вставкой атрибута onclick в тег, но интересно сделать таким методом, но он почему то не работает.

Comment: сейчас кто-нить вам объяснит почему это не работает, а вы просто разместите скрипт после хтмл, с которым работаете

Comment: Ага, спасибо, работает.

Comment: Внимание! Код вида (function(){...})(); выполняется немедленно после загрузки и даже не ждёт подгрузки кода, который следует после. Не забывайте об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, это Вам поможет:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].onclick = function(){
       location.replace("http://www.ya.ru");
    };
};
</script>

<p>click</p>
```

Только нужно для ссылки всё переделать.

Answer (score 0):

<a href="#" id="login">Войти</a>

```
(function () {
    document.getElementById('login').onclick = function () {
        return function() {
            alert(123);
        };
    };
})();
```